# vue-i18n this.$tc is not a function

Tags: vue.js, vue-i18n

My lang file:

```
AccountNotifications: {
  createdWithName: 'Account «{account}» created',
  created: 'Account created | Accounts created',
}
```

my submit method

```
submit() 
   this.$notifications.add({
        type: 'success',
        html: accounts.length === 1
        ? this.$tc('AccountNotifications.created', 1)
        : this.$tc('AccountNotifications.created', 2),
  });
```

My output

```
app.js:290949 TypeError: this.$tc is not a function
```

Whats wrong?

Comment: Please share the component code that contains submit method.

Answer (score 10):

$tc() is not actually needed.  The $t() function supports pluralization now.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Was beating myself up over this. The official guide hasn't been updated yet, so I was pretty clueless to why that was happening.